# ObjectOutputStream vs FileOutputStream и ... сериализация serialVersionUID

Tags: java, serializable

Господа,

позволю себе три вопроса в рамках одной тематики.

1. при сериализации класса, имплементирующего Serializable настоятельно рекомендуется указывать serialVersionUID, поле типа long с модификаторами static final
   Но, вроде бы, static поля не сериализуются.
   Значит, если я правильно понимаю, в поток данных не попадает и из потока не извлекается.
   В таком случае вопрос - какая в нем польза?

И какая именно неприятность может произойти, если serialVersionUID не указан? Тем более, что, как я читал, JVM, не найдя этого поля, подставит его значение по своему разумению.

2. неоднократно встречал следующий пример сериализации объекта в файл:

   ```
   SerializationSample instance = new SerializationSample();
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("o.ser")));
   oos.writeObject( instance );
   oos.close();
   ```

При этом ObjectOutputStream и FileOutputStream находятся на одном уровне иерархии, наследуя OutputStream. 
Зачем после FileOutputStream обертывать еще и в ObjectOutputStream?

3. Насколько я знаю, если default механизм сериализации вас чем-то не устраивает, вы можете переопределить readObject(), writeObject().

Тогда зачем нужен Externalizable с его readExternal(), writeExternal()?

Или я ошибаюсь ... только заметил, что эти два метода почему-то private и не могут быть переопределены?

Кстати, эквивалентен ли термин Externalization термину Serialization?

Заранее всем ответившим спасибо

Answer (score 3):

1. Вы частично правы, serialVersionUID не сериализуется с остальными полями объекта, но он присутсвует в потоке данных как часть header, где также указываются магические символы для определения, что это формат java serialization. Также в header есть полное имя класса. Вы также правы насчет JVM, действительно сгенерируется dynamic serialVersionUID при его отсутствии, но разные JVM по разному калькулируют это значение. Произойдет вот что - java.io.InvalidClassException, т.к. классы будут считаться как local incompatible.
2. ObjectOutputStream позволяет одним вызовом метода писать serializable в стрим, а ObjectInputStream - читать. С FileOutputStream вам необходимо делать все самостоятельно по-байтово.
3. Externalizable - это public интерфейс, следовательно все методы public. Externalizable используется, чтобы сериализировать объект до того, как за него примется java reflection. Имплементация интерфейса полностью отвечает за запись в объект и его чтение, и почти всегда быстрее чем Serializable readObject/writeObject, которые проходят другой пайплайн с java reflection, особенно с большими и сложными объектами. Serializable, однако, позволяет автоматически генерировать данные при добавлении новых полей, что в Externalizable надо делать вручную каждый раз при изменении класса. Грубо говоря оба интерфейса похожи и дают знать пользователю, что класс поддерживает возможность записи в промежуточный формат и его последующего чтения, будь это файл, сетевой пакет или массив байтов.

Comment: вы говорите, что в заголовке передается полное имя класса, а как его можно поменять, если на принимающей стороне оно будет отличаться, что бы это не было хаком, есть ли какой либо корректный способ решить эту задачу?